# Credit Card processor for UK company recommendations?

Tags: payments, payment-gateway

I'm looking for recommendations for a credit card processor to handle payments for purchases from an online store. The requirements are

- hosted payments page with state-of-the-art UX, and able to be configured to match the -parent website's look and feel as closely as possible
- settlement into a UK merchant account or includes merchant facility and can settle to a UK company with a UK bank acct, in GBP.
- looking to minimise PCI requirements for the parent web site as far as possible
- reliable and good support
- payments page doesn't require Verified By Visa or SecureCode
- ideally payments page can do multi-currency
- shopping cart is not required

The UK-based processors I've found so far all have hosted payments pages that look like they are from the mid-1990's. Nice UX is a key requirement.

Suggestions based on personal experience preferred.

Comment: "payments page doesn't require Verified By Visa or SecureCode" - is that even a feasible requirement nowadays?

Comment: it is - we use such a service, but unfortunately they can't settle to to a UK bank acct.

Answer (score -1):

I like authorize.net for a payment gateway.

Comment: They're only available in the US and even then you still need a merchant account to actually process payments.